Nginx conf ASP.Net will not show apps
I have 4 ASP.Net applications I am trying to show with Nginx. I cannot get them to work. No matter what configurations I have tried seem to work. I am desperate. Please help what am I doing wrong?
Here is my Nginx.Conf:
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

   server {
       listen 80 default_server;
       listen [::]:80 default_server;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

       location /auth {
           proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5160;
           proxy_http_version 1.0;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
           proxy_intercept_errors on;
       }

       location /company {
           proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5287;
           proxy_http_version 1.0;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
           proxy_intercept_errors on;
       }

       location /equipment {
           proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5176;
           proxy_http_version 1.0;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
           proxy_intercept_errors on;
       }

       location /featureflags {
           proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5291;
           proxy_http_version 1.0;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
           proxy_intercept_errors on;
       }

       error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
       location = /50x.html {
           root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
       }

       error_page 400 401 402 403 404 /40x.html;
       location = /40x.html {
           root /usr/share/nginx/html;
       }
   }
}

My applications should be reachable at the following addresses:
http://localhost:5160/api/health/healthCheck --> Authentication
http://localhost:5291/api/health/healthCheck --> FeatureFlags
http://localhost:5176/api/health/healthCheck --> Equipment
http://localhost:5287/api/health/healthCheck --> Company


You need to turn on proxy_intercept_errors; 2) Trailing slash you are using at the end of  proxy_pass directive parameter counts as an URI part, causing transform of the requests like /company or /equipment to / (read the proxy_pass directive documentation carefully).


@IvanShatsky thank you for the tips. I have updated my question as I am still having issues but now I can at least see the custom 404 page I have instead of 'page not found'

This seems to work so far:
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

   server {
       listen 80 default_server;
       listen [::]:80 default_server;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

       location /auth/ {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5160/;
           proxy_http_version 1.0;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
           proxy_intercept_errors on;
       }

       location /company/ {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5287/;
           proxy_http_version 1.0;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
           proxy_intercept_errors on;
       }

       location /equipment/ {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5176/;
           proxy_http_version 1.0;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
           proxy_intercept_errors on;
       }

       location /featureflags/ {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5291/;
           proxy_http_version 1.0;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
           proxy_intercept_errors on;
       }

       error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
       location = /50x.html {
           root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
       }

       error_page 400 401 402 403 404 /40x.html;
       location = /40x.html {
           root /usr/share/nginx/html;
       }
   }
}

I needed to changes these lines from this:
location /auth {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5160;

To this:
location /auth/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5160/;


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
